# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No application context active

Tags: seam2

I am getting illegal state exception in below code at 
`PropertyDao propertyDao = PropertyDao.getInstance();`

```
public class JMySpellCheckerServlet extends TinyMCESpellCheckerServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2460237918745522935L;
    private SpellChecker loadSpellChecker(final String lang) throws SpellCheckException
    {      
       PropertyDao propertyDao = PropertyDao.getInstance();
       McsProperty messageLangProperty = 
       propertyDao.getMcsProperty(PropertyDao.PROPERTY_MESSAGE_LANG);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the @Application context is not yet available... you can set it up explicitly like this (before calling PropertyDao.getInstance):

```
if ( !Contexts.isApplicationContextActive() ) {
    Lifecycle.setupApplication();
}
```